# Why default lines for One2many fields are not filling in related and default values automatically in Odoo 13?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I have a button in the model `sale.order` with executes the method `action_open_certification_views`. This method opens the `sale.certification` tree view. So the method returns the dictionary of the action which opens the `sale.certification` views, and I have added the following context to auto-fill in the `sale.certification` fields (`sale_id` and `line_ids`, where `line_ids` is a One2many field pointing to `sale.certification.line`):

```
def action_open_certification_views(self):
    ...
    action['context'] = {
        'default_name': 'My Certification',
        'default_sale_id': self.id,
        'default_line_ids': [
            (0, 0, {
                'quantity': 5.0,
                'sale_line_id': line.id,
            }) for line in self.order_line
        ],
    }
    return action
```

When I click on the button, the `sale.certification` tree view is opened right, and if click on *Create* button, the context of the action is working well since I see the `sale.certification` form filled in automatically with the default name *My Certification*, the right link to sale order, and the same number of certification lines as sale order lines has the sale order. Each of this certification lines has quantity 5.0, and the link to sale order line is right too.

The problem is that the `sale.certification.line` model has many other fields which are related or which have default values, but these certification lines filled in by default by the action context are not filling in those fields.

For example, there is another field `quantity2` in `sale.certification.line` model, and visible in the view, which always takes by default 1.0. However, the field is empty in all default lines. Same problem with related fields. There are some related fields in the view which take their values through `sale_line_id` field. These one is filled in OK, but the related fields remain empty. For example, in `sale.certification.line model there is this field:

```
product_uom = fields.Many2one(
    related='sale_line_id.product_uom',
)
```

In spite of having `sale_line_id` filled in OK in all lines, they have `product_uom` empty. Can anyone tell me why? Do I have to specify their values in context too, despite they should have been filled in by theirselves?

Comment: Seems like a "bug" or a limitation of the framework. I would open an Issue in Github.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/69641. Let's see if I am ignored forever...

Comment: hopefully you don't get the usual question "did you try it in runbot", which ofcourse makes no sense at all in this issue :D i'll see, because i've subscribed to it.